# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. when publishing to web server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I know that this question was asked so many times but none of the theme worked for me.
I have published a mvc website to a plesk control panel web server but I continuously get this error:

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on ? I spent three days and tried everything.
here is my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="application" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=bug.mdf;Integrated Security=false; User ID=admin;Password=###############" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2434922
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5736592
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +940
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +272
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +280
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +356
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__19(DbConnection conn) +119
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +443
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +556
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +86
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +164
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +151
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Linq.Queryable.OrderByDescending(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector) +83
```

Comment: The error say it is trying to connect to master db which should not be used r altered for your application it is used  by sql server for its purpose so you need to add your db  name in the connection string

Comment: I forgot to write data base name in question but  data base name is not problem.

Comment: Then if it is not issue then the user who is trying to create a new Db should have correct permission in sql server to crete DB

Comment: no , I checked that too , i created  a table from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio whit that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is entirely straight-forward. Your application is attempting to create a database and the database user it's connecting with does not have that permission. As to *why* that's occurring, it's difficult to say with the infomation provided. Assuming you're not actually attempting to explicitly create a database in your code, it's most likely due to the database initialization strategy set on your context. The default is to attempt to create the database if it does not exist. As a result, you should ensure that the instance you're connecting to does indeed have the database your application is attempting to work with.

You *could* also simply give the DB user permission to create the database, but that would be an extremely bad idea, security wise. Your web application's DB user should always have the most limited set of permissions possible, basically just SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE, and maybe not even all of those. You might need EXECUTE as well in some scenarios, but you can grant that on an object-by-object basis, rather than globally.

Comment: I created database from web server control panel . the problem rises when my app wants to connect to database and initializing for the first time.

Comment: Either that didn't actually complete as you think it did, or the connection string is not actually referencing the correct instance/database. Either way, EF is pretty sure it still doesn't have a database, so that's what you need to figure out.

Comment: how can i figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the database name i.e initial catalog in your connection string

```
   <connectionStrings>
  <add name="application" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NameOFDB; Integrated Security=false; User    ID=admin;Password=#slfsl$4554sll%" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed write database name.